# Redirecting after fetch post in node.js with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect, fetch

I have ejs page(/profile/addcalender) and I am taking data from that page by using fetch with post. I can take and process data in my serverside post method but ı can not redirect after it.

Here is the related part of the ejs page:

```
<li><button class="contact100"  id='nextstp' style="width: 100%; height: 100px; font-size: larger; padding-bottom: 0px;"> <span>SCHEDULE</span></button></li>
```

This is the related part of .js file connected to ejs to take data and where I use fetch:

```
function moveon(){  //Collecting data in here // Bu fonksiyon da dataları toplaman lazım !!
 var mailler = mails; // ALL mails
 var Title = document.getElementById("title").value; // Meeting Title
 var desc = document.getElementById("description").value; // Meeting Description

 if(!Title){alert("Cannot Submit without title"); return;}
 if(!desc){alert("Description is mandatory"); return;}
 if(mails.length < 1){alert("You need AT LEAST one attendee"); return;}

 var stuff = {title: Title, decription: desc, mails:mailler}
 console.log(stuff);
 console.log(JSON.stringify(stuff));

 var stuff2 = {title : "alex", description: "de souza"};
 options = {
   method : 'POST',
   redirect: 'follow',
   body: JSON.stringify(stuff),
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   }
 };

 fetch('/profile/addcalender', options);

}
```

Here is the where I take post request with express:

```
  router.get('/addcalender', (req,res) => {
  //console.log(req.user);

   res.render('calendermeet',{user:req.user});
  })

  router.post('/addcalender', userController.postCalenderMeet);
```

Here is where I process data in server-side in usercontroller:

```
module.exports.postCalenderMeet = (req, res, next) => {
console.log("POST CALENDAR MEEEET")

async function main() {

    var userCalendars = [];

    for (email of req.body.mails) {
        await User.findOne({
            email: email
        }).then(user => {
            if (user) {
                //console.log(user.name);
                //console.log(user.calender);
                userCalendars.push(user.calender)
            }
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    userCalendars.push(req.user.calender);

    console.log("1");
    console.log(userCalendars);
    console.log("2");

    res.redirect("/profile/calender");

    return userCalendars;

  }

  main();



 };
```

In normally I take post requests from form and at the server-side redirecting works. But when I used fetch it does not redirecting and I am staying on the same page.

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75188418/17865804)

Answer (score 2):

A redirect means "What you asked for can be found here".

It doesn't mean "Navigate the main browser window here".

The browser will follow the redirect automatically and make the response available via the `fetch` API.

If you want to navigate to a new page: **don't use `fetch`**. The entire point of it is to make an HTTP request **without** navigating.

Use a form instead.

Comment: Thanks for answer I will try to do it by using form, but still is there a way to do using fetch.

Comment: No, there isn't.